# Print stack trace in reverse with Ruby 3, Rails 6 and Puma

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, puma

Is there an easy way to reverse the stack trace when printed by puma? It's quite tedious scroll up the whole stack trace just to see that you have made a typo. Here is an example:

```
uninitialized constant Treasure
/workspace/app/graphql/types/query_type.rb:7:in `<class:QueryType>'
/workspace/app/graphql/types/query_type.rb:3:in `<module:Types>'
/workspace/app/graphql/types/query_type.rb:1:in `<main>'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/zeitwerk-2.4.2/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:26:in `require'
/workspace/app/graphql/workspace_schema.rb:3:in `<class:WorkspaceSchema>'
/workspace/app/graphql/workspace_schema.rb:1:in `<main>'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/zeitwerk-2.4.2/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:26:in `require'
/workspace/app/controllers/graphql_controller.rb:12:in `execute'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/actionpack-6.1.3.2/lib/action_controller/metal/basic_implicit_render.rb:6:in `send_action'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/actionpack-6.1.3.2/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:228:in `process_action'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/actionpack-6.1.3.2/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:30:in `process_action'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/actionpack-6.1.3.2/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:42:in `block in process_action'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-6.1.3.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:106:in `run_callbacks'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/actionpack-6.1.3.2/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:41:in `process_action'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/actionpack-6.1.3.2/lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:22:in `process_action'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/actionpack-6.1.3.2/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:34:in `block in process_action'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-6.1.3.2/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:203:in `block in instrument'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-6.1.3.2/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:24:in `instrument'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-6.1.3.2/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:203:in `instrument'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/actionpack-6.1.3.2/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:33:in `process_action'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/actionpack-6.1.3.2/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:249:in `process_action'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-6.1.3.2/lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:27:in `process_action'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/actionpack-6.1.3.2/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:165:in `process'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/actionpack-6.1.3.2/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:190:in `dispatch'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/actionpack-6.1.3.2/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:254:in `dispatch'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/actionpack-6.1.3.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:50:in `dispatch'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/actionpack-6.1.3.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:33:in `serve'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/actionpack-6.1.3.2/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:50:in `block in serve'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/actionpack-6.1.3.2/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:32:in `each'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/actionpack-6.1.3.2/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:32:in `serve'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/actionpack-6.1.3.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:842:in `call'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/warden-1.2.9/lib/warden/manager.rb:36:in `block in call'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/warden-1.2.9/lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/warden-1.2.9/lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/etag.rb:27:in `call'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/conditional_get.rb:40:in `call'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/head.rb:12:in `call'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-6.1.3.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:601:in `call'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/actionpack-6.1.3.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `block in call'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-6.1.3.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:98:in `run_callbacks'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/actionpack-6.1.3.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:26:in `call'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/actionpack-6.1.3.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/actionpack-6.1.3.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/actionable_exceptions.rb:18:in `call'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/actionpack-6.1.3.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:29:in `call'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/actionpack-6.1.3.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:33:in `call'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-6.1.3.2/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:37:in `call_app'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-6.1.3.2/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `block in call'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-6.1.3.2/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:99:in `block in tagged'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-6.1.3.2/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:37:in `tagged'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-6.1.3.2/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:99:in `tagged'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-6.1.3.2/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/actionpack-6.1.3.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:81:in `call'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/actionpack-6.1.3.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:26:in `call'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-6.1.3.2/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:29:in `call'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/actionpack-6.1.3.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/actionpack-6.1.3.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:24:in `call'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:110:in `call'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/actionpack-6.1.3.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/host_authorization.rb:98:in `call'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/rack-cors-1.1.1/lib/rack/cors.rb:100:in `call'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-6.1.3.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:539:in `call'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/puma-5.3.1/lib/puma/configuration.rb:249:in `call'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/puma-5.3.1/lib/puma/request.rb:76:in `block in handle_request'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/puma-5.3.1/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:338:in `with_force_shutdown'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/puma-5.3.1/lib/puma/request.rb:75:in `handle_request'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/puma-5.3.1/lib/puma/server.rb:437:in `process_client'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/puma-5.3.1/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:145:in `block in spawn_thread'
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 5ms (Views: 1.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 2510)
```

It would be much more convenient if `uninitialized constant Treasure` were shown at the bottom. I've done some research and it seems like it should have been implemented with Ruby 2.5. Maybe I can configure puma somehow to do this?

I'm using Ruby 3 and Rails 6.

Comment: Maybe [`ActiveSupport::BacktraceCleaner`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/BacktraceCleaner.html) could help to get rid of unwanted lines.

Comment: @Stefan Thank for showing me the `BacktraceCleaner`, but I want to reverse the stack not clean it.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is to [add a middleware](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/rails_on_rack.html#adding-a-middleware) to the end of your middleware list, catch the exception there and reverse it.

```
module MyApp
  class FlipExceptions
  
    def initialize(app)
      @app = app
    end

    def call(env)
      return @app.call(env)
    rescue StandardError => e
      trace = e.backtrace.reverse
      e.set_backtrace(trace)
      raise e
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I've tried to get this to work by adding in my `development.rb`: `config.middleware.use Workspace::ReverseBacktrace`.  `ReverseBacktrace` is the class you provided.  After this changes I've started puma, but the stack trace stays the same. Any ideas what is wrong?

Comment: Can you put some log/breakpoint in the middleware ? wondering if it's catching the exception or not

Comment: Thank you for looking into my issue. Yes, I've set a break point and a log, but neither stopped nor printed something.